# splitting accommodation costs between people when some of them stay for fewer days

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We're 4 people and we are staying 7 nights, for a total cost of 546.
One of us however is leaving 1 day earlier.
Initially I thought the problem was very simple.
I reasoned that the 3 of us staying for the full period should pay $C_1$, and the person leaving earlier should pay $C_2$, under the following conditions:

$3 \cdot C_1 + C_2 = 546$

$C_2 = \frac 6 7 \cdot C_1$

The result was:

$C_1 = \frac {1274} 9 \approx 141.56$

$C_2 = \frac {364} 3 \approx 121.33$

I was happy with this, but then I thought: how am I going to explain it to the group?
So I tried a more 'intuitive' approach, which I believed was equivalent.
I reasoned that the first 6 nights should be split equally between all 4 of us, whereas the last night should only be split between the 3 of us who were still staying at that point.

Cost of each night:

$\frac {546} 7 = 78$

Cost of the first 6 nights:

$78 \cdot 6 = 468$

Split equally between 4 of us:

$\frac {468} 4 = 117$

Cost of the last night split only between 3 of us:

$\frac {78} 3 = 26$

Which would give:

$C_1 = 117 + 26 = 143$

$C_2 = 117$

The first condition above is still met:

$3 \cdot 143 + 117 = 546$

but the second is not:

$\frac 6 7 \cdot 143 \approx 122.57 \ne 117$

I can see that the two approaches are algebraically different, but I don't understand why they are *conceptually* different.
How can looking at 1 day at a time be different from looking at the total? Shouldn't the person staying 1 day less always be paying 6/7 of what the others pay? Or should the 6/7 condition perhaps be applied not to the cost each of the 3 people staying 7 days pays, but (somehow) to the total?

I'm sure there is a simple explanation, but I can't immediately see it. Any idea?
And do you think either of the two approaches is 'fairer'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we both buy a £10 meal every day that we are on holiday and you stay for 6 nights while I stay for 7 then your meal costs will be 6/7 of mine.  But if the daily cost isn't constant, that doesn't apply.

The constant cost per day assumption doesn't apply to your situation: the daily cost goes up when there are fewer people sharing.  That's why your first method overcharges the 6-night guest and why it's inconsistent with the second.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand what you mean. In our case the cost per day is fixed, because it's a shared apartment, not individual rooms in a hotel, so collectively we pay 78 per day regardless of how many people are there. On the other hand, the cost *per person* per day, which is 19.5 on the first 6 days, becomes, indeed as you point out, higher (26) on the last day because there are only 3 people left. I am still unsure which method is fairer though, because by the second method the person leaving earlier sort of forces the rest of the group to pay in full for her unused day.

Answer (score 0):

The early bird gets a refund of 546/(4*7) = 19.5 to be paid by the other three at 6.50 each.

Comment: Thank you William, that's indeed a neat way of looking at it without using equations or complicated fractions; I will probably use your version to explain the final cost to the group.